# Removing transient part in equation and solving for a general form

Tags: equation-solving, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry, control-systems, integral-transforms

I have the following code that I run:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
Ia = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ib = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
Ic = LaplaceTransform[((78)/(10^5))*Sin[2*Pi*5*t], t, s];
R1 = 1/(s*C1);
R2 = 1/(s*C2);
R3 = 1/(s*C3);
R4 = 1;
C1 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C2 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
C3 = ((1124)/10^3)*10^(-9);
FullSimplify[
 InverseLaplaceTransform[
  I4 /. FullSimplify[
     Solve[{Ia == I1 + I4, I2 == I1 + I5, I3 == I2 + I6, 
       Ic == I3 + I4, Ic == Ib + I6, Ib == Ia + I5, 
       I1 == (V1 - V2)/R1, I2 == (V2 - V3)/R2, I3 == V3/R3, 
       I4 == V1/R4}, {I1, I2, I3, I4, I5, I6, V1, V2, V3}]][[1]], s, 
  t]]

Out[1]=(58500000 (281 E^(-750000000000 t/281) \[Pi] - 
   281 \[Pi] Cos[10 \[Pi] t] + 
   75000000000 Sin[10 \[Pi] t]))/(5625000000000000000000 + 
 78961 \[Pi]^2)
```

I want to do two things to the output of this code:

1. I want to remove the transient part of the equation. So I can do that by using `Expand[]` and after that looking for each individual term that gives $\displaystyle\lim_{t\to\infty}y_n(t)=0$. But is there a way to let Mathematica do that?
2. After the transient part is removed, I want to find $I_4(t)$ in the standard form:
   $$I_4(t)=a\sin(\omega t+\varphi)\tag1$$
   Where $a$, $\omega$ and $\varphi$ needs to be found using Mathematica.

Can someone help me with how I can do this in Mathematica? Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be

```
Clear["Global`*"]
expr = (58500000 (281 E^(-750000000000 t/281) π - 281 π Cos[10 π t] 
      + 75000000000 Sin[10 π t]))/(5625000000000000000000 + 78961 π^2);

expr  = Expand[expr];
expr2 = Simplify[If[MatchQ[#,_.*Exp[__*t]],Limit[#,t->Infinity],#]&/@expr];

(Expand@Numerator[expr2]/.a_.*Cos[w_ t]+b_.*Sin[w_ t]
           :>Sqrt[a^2+b^2]*Sin[w*t+ArcTan[b/a]])/Denominator[expr2]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
expr = (58500000 (281 E^(-750000000000 t/281) \[Pi] - 
      281 \[Pi] Cos[10 \[Pi] t] + 
      75000000000 Sin[10 \[Pi] t]))/(5625000000000000000000 + 
    78961 \[Pi]^2);
```

Then

```
expr1 = expr /. Exp[Rational[a_, b_]*t] -> 0 /. 
  a_*Cos[10 \[Pi] t] + b_*Sin[10*\[Pi]*t] -> 
   Sqrt[a^2 + b^2] Sin[10*\[Pi]*t + ArcTan[a, b]]

(*  -((58500000 Sin[10 \[Pi] t - ArcTan[75000000000/(281 \[Pi])]])/Sqrt[
 5625000000000000000000 + 78961 \[Pi]^2])  *)
```

To see it better below I show the result as an image:

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: The problem with `Exp[Rational[a_, b_]*t] -> 0` is that it also makes `Exp[3/2*t]` goes to zero. Which is not correct, as this term does not go to zero in the limit

Comment: @Nasser You are right, but OP only asked about the expression containing a single specific exponential function. In such cases, for the sake of being fast in calculations, I always prefer to make a specific replacement, rather than a general one. In general case, of course you are right, and one easily corrects this as follows: `Exp[Rational[a_, b_]*t] /; a < 0 && b > 0 -> 0` or likewise.